# Fragment lifecycle error in 4.4, onCreateView() is called on multiple fragments same time

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-lifecycle

I am getting error :

In error, Android framework is calling **onCreateView()** of multiple fragment at the same time

[image]

I have **Navigation Drawer** with 3 `FrameLayout` : A, B , C

1.) Through B Option of drawer, User reached to B2 Fragment.

2.)User presses **Home Key** on **B2** fragment and goes to Home screen.

3.) User **Long Press Home Key**, opens this application from **Recents Activity** of Android

Here I am getting error which is shown in picture with **1** in Blue color

My multiple fragments are getting `onCreate()` , `onCreateView()` and `onActivityCreated()` events and so i am losing fragment state of **B2** and my application goes to default fragment which is **A1** (opening from drawer option A)

I have also saved my state of B2 with `onSaveInstanceState()` and restored with `onActivityCreated()` but this approach is not working because `onActivityCreated()` is called of B2 first and then A1 second. So, my B2 fragment is not visible on screen in foreground. Instead of this, A1 becomes visible on screen

Note :

I have used `.replace()` in switching fragments in all cases

This same code is running correct in Android 5.0+ (Lollipop) and gives error in 4.4 (and older version)

Can anybody suggest any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was coming due to Developer Settings -> Do Not Keep Activities (Destroy every activity as soon as the user leaves it)

[image]

The abnormal behaviour was coming because I had turned this option **ON**

This option will cause callback to `onDestroy()` method of every activity when user leaves it. In my case, i was using `fragment` so the events took place :

```
Fragment.onSaveInstanceState()
Activity.onStop()
Fragment.onDestroyView()
Activity.onDestroy()
```

This option is **OFF** for users by default by manufecturers.

This options has pros and cons described : [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21227623/whats-the-main-advantage-and-disadvantage-of-do-not-keep-activities-in-android/30392774#30392774)